# How to use toastify-js with laravel 5.6?

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications

Toastify JS: https://apvarun.github.io/toastify-js/

I want to integrate toastify js with my laravel project for toast notification.

Comment: The documentation should give you some pretty good direction: https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I have read the documentation. Can't integrate with laravel.

Comment: What exactly isn't working when you follow the steps?

Answer (score 0):

> Incase of laravel, you have add it inside header and footer app.css and app.js. Same as HTML we done.

**Adding ToastifyJs to HTML page using the traditional method**

To start using Toastify, add the following CSS on to your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">
```

And the script at the bottom of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js"></script>
```

Files are delivered via the CDN service provided by jsdeliver

Documentation

```
Toastify({
  text: "This is a toast",
  duration: 3000,
  destination: "https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js",
  newWindow: true,
  close: true,
  gravity: "top", // `top` or `bottom`
  positionLeft: true, // `true` or `false`
  backgroundColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
}).showToast();
```

Comment: I want to show toast notification when an action is completed. For example, each CRUD operations.

Comment: You should use ajax for that. Return a message while return from controller.